# batch to find a string of numbers from tsv or text file and put it into a variable

Tags: batch-file

I have a .tsv file that I would like to use a batch file to search for a string of numbers after some text "sampletext 1345678" at the 3rd line of the tsv file. I would like to put the numbers into a variable then print that variable in a temporary text file. I've tried  searching for something like this but nothing matches what I would like to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
set "var="
for /f "skip=2tokens=2" %%i in (whatever.tsv) do if not defined var set var=%%i
echo found %var%
```

should accomplish this (as a batchfile snippet)